# How can i sort a list in python so that two values with the same class would not be neighbors?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list with classes in python, for example `list1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]`. I want to sort a list like this `list 2 = list(range(len(list1))) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` so that two values with the same class won't stand near each other. For my example the result would be `[0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6]`. Number 7 would be left out because I need to try to stick to original list as much as possible. Is there any sorting algorithm for this task? How can I implement it effectively?

Detailed explanation of how I got final list:

1) put value 0 from list2 in the final result list: `res = [0,]`. It has class 1 (list1[0])

2) check next value's from list2 ("1") class. In this example it also is 1, so we don't put them next to each other and move on.

3) check next value's from list2 ("2") class. It class 0, which does not equal to previus value's class, so we can append it to result: `res = [0, 2,]`

4) Now I go back to the value I skipped before ("1") and add it to the final list. `res=[0, 2, 1,]`. Their classes right now are [1, 0, 1].

5) We move on to value "3" from list2. It has class 1, so we cannot add it to the list

6) Move on to value "4" from list2. It's class is 0, so we can add it: `res = [0, 2, 1, 4,]`. Classes of these values look like [1, 0, 1, 0]

7) Go back to value "3", check if we can add it now. Last class in the result list is 0, "3" has class 1, so we can add it. `res = [0, 2, 1, 4, 3,]`, their classes = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

8) Move on to value "5" from list2. It has class 0, add it to the result `res = [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5,]`, their classes = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

9) Move on to value "6" from list2. It has class 1, so I add it to the final list: `res = [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6]`, their classes = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

10) Now I have to check last value from list2 – "7". I can't add it to the list6 because then my classes would look like this: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] and I do not want that to happen, so I just leave out value "7" from the final result.

I can't understand how to code this, especially for a case when i have more then 2 classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "two values with the same class"? All of your values have the class `int`.

Comment: @kaya3 list1 is a list of classes. Both lists have the same size. So for example value 7 from list two would have class 1

Comment: OK. And why leave out number 7 when it's possible to include it? What do you mean by "stick to the original list as much as possible"?

Comment: list2 is an example here. But in my task I got it so it would be ranged in a specific order, where value 0 from list 2 is more important and relevant than value 1 from list 2 and so on. So after values are sorted, their classes would be ```[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] ```. Adding value 7  would mean that classes for the final result would look like ```[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] ``` and I'd prefer to loose value 7 than get this result.

Comment: I think "classes" is the wrong word. "comparison keys" might be more suitable.

Comment: Do you know a systematic way of how to do this by hand? If yes, then describe it in words to us.
As soon as you managed this, you solved the biggest problem and we can guide you to the right python code.

On stack overflow it is common practice to show, which effort you already made and what you tried so far or what ideas you had so far.

Comment: I got pretty close to a solution by binning `list2` based on `list1` then zipping the bins, but it's missing 6 since bin 1 is larger.

Comment: @gelonida thanks for your advice, added detailed algorithm to the question

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to "isolate" each type into their own list, then alternate between them when appending:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
sorted_list = []
sorted_list_indices = []

# Isolate each type to their own list of (index, item)
types = {
    'type0': [(ind, x) for ind, x in enumerate(list1) if x == 0],
    'type1': [(ind, x) for ind, x in enumerate(list1) if x == 1]
    }


# Alternate between the lists of each type, starting with the bigger list
alternator = 'type0' if len(types['type0']) > len(types['type1']) else 'type1'

for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    # Break if one of the lists is empty
    if len(types[alternator]) == 0: break
    # Pop the first item from the "current" list and append it to the output
    tup = types[alternator].pop(0)
    sorted_list_indices.append(tup[0])
    sorted_list.append(tup[1])
    # Switch to the other type
    alternator = 'type0' if alternator == 'type1' else 'type1'

print sorted_list
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
print sorted_list_indices
# [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6]
```

**UPDATE:** Here's another example taking advantage of `zip` built-in function:

```
list1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
sorted_list = []
sorted_list_indices = []

# Isolate each type to their own list of (index, item)
type0 = [(ind, x) for ind, x in enumerate(list1) if x == 0]
# [(2, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)]
type1 = [(ind, x) for ind, x in enumerate(list1) if x == 1]
# [(0, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)]

big_list = type0 if len(type0) > len(type1) else type1
small_list = type0 if len(type0) <= len(type1) else type1

# Shrink the big list to make it larger by one at most
big_list = big_list[:len(small_list)+1]

# Use zip to get a list of tuples as (big_list, small_list)
zipped_list = zip(big_list, small_list)
# [((0, 1), (2, 0)), ((1, 1), (4, 0)), ((3, 1), (5, 0))]

# If big_list is indeed larger, we append its last item to our zipped_list
if len(big_list) > len(small_list): zipped_list.append((big_list[-1],))
# [((0, 1), (2, 0)), ((1, 1), (4, 0)), ((3, 1), (5, 0)), ((6, 1),)]

# Flatten the zipped list of tuples
sorted_list = [tup[1] for zipped in zipped_list for tup in zipped]
sorted_list_indices = [tup[0] for zipped in zipped_list for tup in zipped]

print sorted_list
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
print sorted_list_indices
# [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6]
```